# How to append to an array and return the results in a filter?

Tags: php, filters

i am trying to get array in filters in wordpress i dont khnow how to do it.

```
add_filter('ft_tabs', function ($tabs) {
    return array_push($tabs, array(
        '111' => 'aaa',
        '222' => 'bbb'
    ));
}, 10);

add_filter('ft_tabs', function ($tabs) {
    return array_push($tabs, array(
        '333' => 'ccc',
        '444' => 'ddd'
    ));
}, 15);

$array = array();
$asdasd = apply_filters('ft_tabs', $array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note this is mostly a PHP programming question about arrays and is better asked on e.g. Stack Overflow.

As shown in the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) `array_push()` acts on the array and takes multiple parameters which get added as array values. It doesn't add key => value pairs to associative arrays, and it doesn't return the array itself, so you're probably looking for `array_merge` or just the `+` operator, then returning the new value e.g.

```
add_filter('ft_tabs', function ($tabs) {
    $tabs = $tabs + arrary(
        '111' => 'aaa',
        '222' => 'bbb'
    );
    return $tabs;
}, 10);
```

Also it's poor style to use reserved words like 'array' for variables names as you risk confusing the interpreter and getting a very unexpected result such as calling the `array` function when you meant to get the value of a variable.

Comment: Use `array_merge()` instead of `+` to avoid problems with duplicate keys.